# Randomly generated numbers in a basic array

Tags: java, arrays, random

I simply need to know what i should do to make so that a basic array is filled with randomly generated numbers. now i know how to do that, what i don't know how to to do is to make it so that the randomly generated numbers are bigger than the last number generated all the way through to the end of the array.

Answer (score 2):

Just generate for the list, and then sort them smallest to largest.

```
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
    arr[i] = Random.nextInt(100);
}
Arrays.sort(arr);
```

Comment: for some reason when i code it up it returns arr[i] = Random.nextInt(100), as per the example, not literally as its seen in this question, i get a runtime error on that line. for my actual code it is read as array[x] = gen.nextInt(10000);. i can't say Random.nextInt(num), becuase that would be a static reference to a non static method.

Comment: sorry, i mean to say at the beginning of the comment, that code string causes a runtime error, it doesnt return anything yet.

Answer (score 1):

Generate random numbers, and then sort the array.

You can sort the array using [`Arrays.sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28int%5B%5D%29)

It doesn't make sure that each number is strictly bigger then the previous numbers [it only gurantees `<=`], so if it is an issue - you will have to make sure you have no dupes in the generated numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate an array of random numbers, and then sort it using [Array sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28long%5B%5D%29).

Comment: Yes, now when i go to my driver class to display the array with a S.O.P. i get a runtime error on arr[i] = gen.nextInt(10000); i don't know why is doing that. I set arr[i] = gen.nextInt(10000) into a variable called value, which is an Int

Comment: @Tigh You need to show more code, and add a stack trace. Please edit your question, or better yet ask a new one to get more attention.

Answer (score 1):

There was a comment on the question, I lost the author's name, that recommended adding the randomly generated number to the previous number, which I thought was an interesting approach.

```
arr[0] = Random.nextInt(100);

for(int i = 1; i < arr.length; ++i) {
    arr[i] = arr[i-1] + Random.nextInt(100); 
}
```

This removes the need to sort your result array.

Comment: Note it might fail due to [integer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_overflow)

Comment: @amit, Valid concern, depending on the random range used and the size of the array.

Comment: If the numbers are limited to a specific range, the concern still holds: you might not "overflow", but you might get a number which is out of range.

Comment: @amit yes, if OP is looking for N random numbers 0..M, then the generate and sort approach is best. By random range in my previous content I meant `Random.nextInt(range)`.

Comment: IMO You are limiting yourself for no reason when you are using `nextInt(int)`. You could just fill it up with 4's. Anyway, it is only a point that the OP need to think about when using this solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can have your own algorithm of generating incremental...

For example...

Random each time and add that number to the last one :)

`Random` class in java does not allow you to have a minim limit where to start.. only one...

For example:

```
myArray[0] = Random.nextInt(10000);
for(int i=1; i<myArray.length; i++)
{
    myArray[i] = myArray[i-1]+Random.nextInt(10000);
}
```

So.. it's random and you don't have to sort it.. try keeping everything simple...

Comment: Note that it might fail due to [overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_overflow).

Comment: if he has an array of length 2000000.. yes :) if has only 1000.. no! :)

Comment: (1) You are limiting yourself for no reason when you are using `nextInt(10000)`. You could just fill it up with 4's. (2) You might overflow for when array size is ~200000 [one less zero]. Anyway, it is only a point that the OP need to think about when using this solution.

Comment: Yes, now when i go to my driver class to display the array with a S.O.P. i get a runtime error on arr[i] = gen.nextInt(10000); i don't know why is doing that. I set arr[i] = gen.nextInt(10000) into a variable called value, which is an Int.

Answer (score 0):

I'm **surprised** no one mentioned that we can use `SecureRandom` API to easily generate random arrays *without manually populating it*.

**For ex.** generating a random array of size `100`:

```
SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
int arr[] = random.ints(100).toArray();
```

BTW this should be possible from **java 8** onwards.